# mocha equivalent to webpack's resolve root

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm writing some mocha tests that load code that have paths like this:

```
import MyStore from "stores/MyStore"
```

This works fine in the web browser because we are using the `webpack-dev-server` which in turn reads this entry from `webpack.config.js`: `config.resolve.root: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./app")]` so it knows to find `./app/stores/MyStore`.

This path does not work when running it from `mocha --compilers js:babel/register`.  I'm trying to locate a package or configuration that I may use for this.  It would save us from having to change may code references and of course keep our imports more portable.

Not sure if it matters, we use iojs.  If this really can't be done it would be fine just to update the paths.  Thank you...

Comment: That's a non-standard webpack feature, it probably won't work easily in Node. Why not use standard relative paths?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about including your `app` directory in `$NODE_PATH`:

```
env NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:$PWD/app mocha ...
```

Comment: Windows has environment variables too: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: @jasan take a look at [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) (mentioned in one of the other answers)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cross-platform method. First install `cross-env`:

```
npm install cross-env --save-dev
```

then in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./app mocha ..."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In windows, I had to do this:

```
set NODE_PATH=%CD%/app&& mocha...
```

for some reason, adding a space after 'app' would cause it not to work